# Trying to access array offset on value of type int Error

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I just don't understand why I can't access created array and display values. If I displaying variable $listing it shows ok, array looks good.

```
  Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('listings', [
        // $Variable - Value
        'heading' => 'Latest Listings',
        'listings' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Listing One',
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dolorem adipisci aliquam ducimus! Sit ipsa, voluptates ab sapiente inventore odit.'
        ],

        [
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Listing Two',
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dolorem adipisci aliquam ducimus! Sit ipsa, voluptates ab sapiente inventore odit.'
        ]     
    ]);
});
```

In views folder listings.php get error "Trying to access array offset on value of type int"

```
<h1> {{ $heading }} </h1>

@if(count($listings) == 0)
    <p>No listings found.</p>
@endif

@foreach($listings as $list)
    <h2>{{ $list['title'] }}</h2>
    <p>{{ $list['description'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Error:
[Can't access aray and display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8BHQ.png)

Comment: doesn't make sense. Issue seems with a different part of the code than what you added.

Comment: Not sure what the thing you showed in the first block is actually supposed to be. As part of a larger array declaration, what you would have there is one array under the key `listings`, and then a second array that comes without a key, so it should get a numeric index then ...?

Comment: Your `listings` appears to be _one_ array, containing elements under the keys `id`, `title` and `description`. So when you loop over that using `foreach($listings as $list)`, the first time `$list` will be the `1` stored under they `id` key. Of course this gets you that error, because `1['title']` is not a thing ...

Answer (score 1):

Your listing needs to be array

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('listings', [
        // $Variable - Value
        'heading' => 'Latest Listings',
        'listings' =>[ [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'Listing One',
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dolorem adipisci aliquam ducimus! Sit ipsa, voluptates ab sapiente inventore odit.'
        ],

        [
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'Listing Two',
            'description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio dolorem adipisci aliquam ducimus! Sit ipsa, voluptates ab sapiente inventore odit.'
        ]    
]
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! ok :D it is working  'listings' => [ [ ] ] must be array itself.

Comment: @Mindaugas do you know how to "accept" a working answer?